# Debug push error using SFMC SDK

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, mobilepush-android, push-notification, salesforce-sdk-android

I'm testing to send push notification from SFMC to mobile app using the app configured in MobilePush with FCM server key and APNS p8 Auth Key set.
[image]

I sent a test push notification using Mobile Push:
[image]

The result was the message only pushed to iOS app but not Android app. The audience was selected correctly, as I can find the corresponding error by filtering the contact in SFMC.
[image]

However, I can't find out the reason of error in this page. May I know in SFMC, do we have logs somewhere for debugging?

p.s. I've tried to use my FCM key to send push directly by API, the message can be pushed to my Android app.

Comment: Do you have an open support case?